# Creating Table on Runtime and Passing Values to its cell - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript and i am stuck somewhere in my code of JavaScript.

```
    function GenerateTable() {
    var p_id = document.inner3_form.product_id.value;
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable1");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
```

Problem occurs here. when I hard-code something in the cell like:

```
 *   cell1.innerHTML = "This is Cell 1.";    *
```

Above mentioned code works but when i am trying to pass the values (data fetched from HTML text-field) through the above variables, it does not work like:

```
    cell1.value = p_id;         X
  OR
    cell1.innerHTML = p_id;  
}
```

Can anyone please help me and let me know where I am going wrong in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms#Named_form_access). You are not getting the element product_id.

Add `elements` after the `inner3_form`.

`var p_id = document.inner3_form.ellements.product_id.value;`

Also, check the console for debugging.